# Programming Python for absolute beginners: Chapter 7 Storing Complex Data

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning from "Python programming for the absolute beginner" and have been having fun. The book is written for Python 2.7 (i think), but I've been using Python 3 and translating the code, which is been a fun challenge.

I recently ran into a problem I'm not sure how to fix. On the section labeled: "Pickling Data and Writing It to a File" There's an example where you run the following code:

```
import cPickle, shelve
print "Pickling lists." variety = ["sweet", "hot", "dill"]
shape = ["whole", "spear", "chip"]
brand = ["Claussen", "Heinz", "Vlassic"]
pickle_file = open("pickles1.dat", "w")
cPickle.dump(variety, pickle_file)
cPickle.dump(shape, pickle_file)
cPickle.dump(brand, pickle_file)
pickle_file.close()
```

I translated it to this (for python 3)

```
import pickle, shelve
print ("Pickling lists.")
variety = ["sweet", "hot", "dill"]
shape = ["whole", "spear", "chip"]
brand = ["Classen", "Heinz", "Vlassic"]
pickle_file = open("pickles1.dat", "w")
pickle.dump(variety, pickle_file)
pickle.dump(shape, pickle_file)
pickle.dump(brand, pickle_file)
pickle_file.close()
```

BUT, i get this error/output from IDLE:

```
Pickling lists.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/hypernerdcc/Documents/pickles.py", line 11, in <module>
pickle.dump(variety, pickle_file)
File
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/pickle.py",
line 1345, in dump
Pickler(file, protocol, fix_imports=fix_imports).dump(obj)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to write bytes, ie binary data, to a text file, which will only accept str. Change the file opening flags, it should be:

```
pickle_file = open("pickles1.dat", "wb")
```

With the b flagging it as a binary file, which then will accept bytes.

This is in fact a bug in the book. The binary flag should really be there in the Python 2 code as well.

Comment: The `b` is only necessary in Windows; on Unix-like systems (which the OP is using, as you can tell from the path names in the pasted traceback), the `b` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Wow, plopping the "wb" in place of the "b" allowed the code to run. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's also worth noting for those with a similar issue that in the 2nd half of this example, you need to add an "rb" to the line: pickle_file = open("pickles1.dat", "r")

Comment: @Wooble: And because it's necessary on Windows, it should be there in that book, or in fact always, as your code otherwise might not run on Windows.